# json key has multiple values under a quote, how do i get specific value?

Tags: regex

below is my json

```
 "alerts": [
                {
                    "alert_key": "event_source=service;host_name=hca-prd-sqachy01;service_desc=tcp"
                }
            ]
        },
```

how do i get extract host_name from it? i am expecting answer to be in regex

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (after parsing from JSON using JSON.parse) -

```js
jso = JSON.parse(`{"alerts": [
                {
                    "alert_key": "event_source=service;host_name=hca-prd-sqachy01;service_desc=tcp"
                }
            ]
        }`);

// With regex
console.log(jso.alerts.map(x=>x.alert_key.match(/host_name=([^;]*)/)[1])) // [ "hca-prd-sqachy01"]
```